# Нужен только один map

Tags: golang, map

после цикла создается два ***map*** если append не добавляю то все стерается и остается только последний элемент или

```
[map[title:муцппцп] map[title:fgdfg]]
```

а нужно [map[title:муцппцп title:fgdfg]]

```html
package main
type AutoGeneratedd struct {
 Title       string `json:"title"`
 Description string `json:"description"`
}

func main() {
 setupResponse(w, r)
 var err error
 var data DataTechnicalService
 err = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&data)
 if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
  return
 }

 str, _ := data.Rows.(string) 

 var i []AutoGeneratedd
 var bM []bson.M

 if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &i); err != nil {
  fmt.Println("ugh: ", err)
 }
 fmt.Println(i) //[{муцппцп 5465465} {fgdfg 545454}]
 for _, u := range i {
  bM = append(bM, bson.M{"title": u.Title})
 }

 fmt.Println(bM) //[map[title:муцппцп] map[title:fgdfg]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Golang, как и любой язык программирования, не позволяет создавать два элемента с одним ключом. Например, если ключ `title` уже существует и записать по этому ключу что-то новое, то оно просто заменит его

Чтобы иметь два элемента с одинаковыми ключами, Вам придется хранить два map'a

Comment: Это я понял, но как бдаг записать